# Python doesn't recognize cv2 when running under sudo

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, sudo

I've installed opencv with python 2.7 [using this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/27/installing-opencv-3-0-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/). I've created a test python file and everything works fine. But when I try to run it as sudo, it throws an error:

> ImportError: No module named cv2

I'm guessing this has to do with permissions.. I need to run it as sudo because I'm using pigpiod in another function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may have multiple python installations (only one of which has the opencv module).  Check 'sudo python --version' and compare it to your working one.  If they differ then you have the root to your problem.  Unlikely to be permissions more likely to be missing module in called version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused because when I installed opencv I created it in a virtual env. Making a link to the opencv file from outside the env to the opencv library folder fixed it.